# Get the url of the hyperlink

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have to write xslt to wordml (2007) documents. There are hyperlinks like below.

```
< w:p w:rsidR="00FD086A" w:rsidRDefault="00425A76" w:rsidP="00FD086A">
< w: hyperlink r:id="rId4" w:history="1">
< w:r w:rsidR="00FD086A" w:rsidRPr="00425A76">
< w:rPr>
< w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink"/>
< /w:rPr>
< w:t>google</w:t>
< /w:r>
< /w:hyperlink>
< /w:p>
```

I want to get the url for the link name. In here I want to get the url for the "google" link. I know its there in Relationships, but I can't access that with xslt. Does anybody know? (Probably writing a template?) please help me!

Comment: Your XML doesn't match your description. Where is the URL? Where are the Relationships?

Comment: the url is in "Relationship" of an ordinary word 2007 document.. its like this.
<pkg:xmlData>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
<Relationship Id="rId4" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/hyperlink" Target="http://www.gmail.com/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the following namespace prefixes are declared:

```
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage"
xmlns:rel="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
```

the following XPath can be used to select the value of the URL using the value of the `w:hyperlink/@r:id` (hard-coded value of "rId5" in this example):

```
/pkg:package
  /pkg:part
     /pkg:xmlData
       /rel:Relationships
         /rel:Relationship[@Id='rId5']/@Target
```

You could use it in the context of a template matching on the `w:hyperlink` to produce an HTML anchor element, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="w:hyperlink">
    <a href="{/pkg:package
                /pkg:part
                  /pkg:xmlData
                    /rel:Relationships
                      /rel:Relationship[@Id=current()/@r:id]/@Target}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You are more than awesome! this works like a charm! I wish I could vote up this answer. But I need more reputation for that. This is really really awesome! ^_^

Comment: I have another question. Can you look in to that too? ^_^